# strangest problem with the xml files

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, soap, xml

we are doing mobile app for our site. for doing mobile app, we need session id from server....

we are getting session id. recently we installed one seo extensin

in that extension , there is config.xml file.

there are lot of lines in that xml file. if i remove any one line in that xml file, than

we are getting session id , but problems are happening in magento admin

is there any way that if i remove one line in xml file, than also it should work in admin panel

I am getting this error in admin panel : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_extension_Helper_Validator' not found in app/Mage.php on line 547

this is the config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <extension_Seo>
            <version>0.2.2</version>
        </extension_Seo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <seo>
                <class>extension_Seo_Block</class>
            </seo>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_pager>extension_Seo_Block_Html_Pager</html_pager>
                    <html_head>extension_Seo_Block_Html_Head</html_head>
                    <html_breadcrumbs>extension_Seo_Block_Breadcrumbs</html_breadcrumbs>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
            <review>
                <rewrite>
                    <helper>extension_Seo_Block_Review_Helper</helper>
                    <product_view_list>extension_Seo_Block_Review_Product_View_List</product_view_list>
                    <view>extension_Seo_Block_Review_View</view>
                </rewrite>
            </review>
            <!-- <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <cms_page_grid>extension_Seo_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Grid</cms_page_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml> -->
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <seo>
                <class>extension_Seo_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>seo_resource</resourceModel>
            </seo>
                <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product_attribute_backend_urlkey>extension_Seo_Model_Rewrite_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey</product_attribute_backend_urlkey>
                        <url>extension_Seo_Model_Rewrite_Url</url>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog>
                <enterprise_catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product_url>extension_Seo_Model_Enterprise_Rewrite_Product_Url</product_url>
                    </rewrite>
                </enterprise_catalog>
            <seo_resource>
                <class>extension_Seo_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <rewrite>
                        <table>m_seo_rewrite</table>
                    </rewrite>
                    <rewrite_store>
                        <table>m_seo_rewrite_store</table>
                    </rewrite_store>
                </entities>
            </seo_resource>
            <tag>
                <rewrite>
                    <tag>extension_Seo_Model_Rewrite_Tag</tag>
                </rewrite>
            </tag>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <seo>
                <class>extension_Seo_Helper</class>
            </seo>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <image>extension_Seo_Helper_Rewrite_Image</image>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <seo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>extension_Seo</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </seo_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>checkUrl</method>
                    </m_seo_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
            <controller_action_layout_render_before>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_meta>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>applyMeta</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_meta>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_render_before>

            <adminhtml_catalog_category_tabs>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_categorytab>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>addCategorySeoTab</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_categorytab>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_catalog_category_tabs>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <seo>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>extension_Seo_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>addSeoUrlsRouter</method>
                    </seo>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_product_urls>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>setupProductUrls</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_product_urls>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
            <controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_paging>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>setupPagingMeta</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_paging>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view>
            <controller_action_layout_render_before_attributepages_page_view> <!-- support of TM_Attributepages -->
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_paging>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>setupPagingMeta</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_paging>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_render_before_attributepages_page_view>
            <catalog_controller_product_init_after>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_controller_product>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>checkProductUrlRedirect</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_controller_product>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_init_after>
            <controller_front_send_response_before>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_http_response_send_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>httpResponseSendBeforeEvent</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_http_response_send_before>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_send_response_before>
            <clean_catalog_images_cache_after>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_clean_catalog_images_cache_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>onCleanCatalogImagesCacheAfter</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_clean_catalog_images_cache_after>
                </observers>
            </clean_catalog_images_cache_after>
            <catalog_product_save_after>  <!-- for Magento Enterprise only -->
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_create_product_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>extension_Seo_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updateUrlKeyByTemplateIfEmpty</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_create_product_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <seo>
                    <file>seo.xml</file>
                </seo>
                        </updates>
        </layout>
         <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_snippets_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/snippets_observer</class>
                        <method>addProductSnippets</method>
                    </m_seo_snippets_observer>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
            <catalog_helper_output_construct>
                <observers>
                    <m_seo_observer_attributes>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomAttributeOutputHandler</method>
                    </m_seo_observer_attributes>
                </observers>
            </catalog_helper_output_construct>
         </events>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <extension_Seo>
                    <files>
                        <default>extension_Seo.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </extension_Seo>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <seo>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>extension_Seo</module>
                    <frontName>seo</frontName>
                </args>
            </seo>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <extension_Seo>
                    <files>
                        <default>extension_Seo.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </extension_Seo>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <seo>
                    <file>seo.xml</file>
                </seo>
                <seo>
                    <file>mst_seo.xml</file>
                </seo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <cms_page_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <seo_cms_save_page>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/system_cms_observer</class>
                        <method>savePage</method>
                    </seo_cms_save_page>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_prepare_save>
            <adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form>
                <observers>
                    <seo_cms_prepare_form>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seo/system_cms_observer</class>
                        <method>prepareForm</method>
                    </seo_cms_prepare_form>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <seo>
            <general>
                <is_add_canonical_url>1</is_add_canonical_url>
                <crossdomain></crossdomain>
                <trailing_slash>0</trailing_slash>
                <canonical_url_ignore_pages><![CDATA[catalogsearch_result_index
catalogsearch_advanced_index
catalogsearch_advanced_result
checkout_cart_index
checkout_onepage_index
cms_index_noroute]]></canonical_url_ignore_pages>
                <layered_navigation_friendly_urls>1</layered_navigation_friendly_urls>
                <is_enable_image_friendly_urls>0</is_enable_image_friendly_urls>
                <image_url_template>[product_name]</image_url_template>
                <is_enable_image_alt>0</is_enable_image_alt>
                <image_alt_template>[product_name]</image_alt_template>
                <breadcrumbs_separator><![CDATA[&rarr;]]></breadcrumbs_separator>
                <is_category_meta_tags_used>1</is_category_meta_tags_used>
                <is_product_meta_tags_used>1</is_product_meta_tags_used>
            </general>
        </seo>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Removing just one line from the config will leave it invalid config file for entire Magento application. You should consult with the extension developer regarding why you are not able to get the session id. There are a lot of events being observed and a lot of core rewrites going on here. One/many of them might be interfering with the way you used to get session ids.

Comment: extension team did't replied for this

Comment: Then, you are in for a 'Magento Show'. Try removing nodes one by one to see which event/rewrite is causing the problem. After you identify that, post it's code here.

Comment: i deleted all template files except that config.xml file , but still i did't got session id.


but if i remove one line from that xml means , i am getting the session id. but as you said removing the line from xml file means

disablingt the extension right? i will try with nodes now....

Comment: It's not template files playing with you, events will be in observers and rewrites in their respective locations. You should look into the code folders of module.

Comment: Is the code of extension open-source ? Try giving a link to it in your question if it is. Someone here might have experience with that.

Comment: no, its paid extension

Comment: i deleted all core template and all other folders but i did't got session id , i got only when i deleted the line in config.xml filem, now i will check with nodes

Comment: please post your comment as answer, its alll related to some nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing just one line from the config will leave it invalid config file for entire Magento application. You should consult with the extension developer regarding why you are not able to get the session id.

There are a lot of events being observed and a lot of core rewrites going on here. One/many of them might be interfering with the way you used to get session ids.